# ISJSON function in SQL server is inconsistent

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL server 2016 (SP3) enterprise edition.
I faced strange behavior. Took two different **VALID** JSONs defined as VARCHAR(8000) and checked whether they valid. One of them is 2484 length and one 4294 length.
One (the short one) returned true (valid) and one (long one) false (0=not valid).
Once I cast the not valid JSON to VARCHAR(max) - it returned true.
What's happen here?

```sql
DECLARE @parameter VARCHAR(8000)='{"ExpressionsArray":[{"Priority":2,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":11,"AttributeFieldName":"STR101","OperatorId":"14","OperatorValue":"Contains","Value":"ci","FormatType":"text"}],"Value":"city good2"},{"Priority":3,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":12,"AttributeFieldName":"FIELD339","OperatorId":"11","OperatorValue":"Between","Value":"70,80","FormatType":"between numbers"}],"Value":"very good"},{"Priority":4,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":13,"AttributeFieldName":"STR1","OperatorId":"11","OperatorValue":"Between","Value":"2022-08-02,2022-08-05","FormatType":"between dates"}],"Value":"date between 1"},{"Priority":5,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":14,"AttributeFieldName":"STR11","OperatorId":"5","OperatorValue":"Equals","Value":"lan","FormatType":"text"}],"Value":"lan"},{"Priority":6,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":15,"AttributeFieldName":"STR6","OperatorId":"26","OperatorValue":"This week","Value":"","FormatType":"disable"}],"Value":"This week date"},{"Priority":7,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":16,"AttributeFieldName":"STR7","OperatorId":"19","OperatorValue":"Today","Value":"","FormatType":"disable"}],"Value":"Today - date"},{"Priority":8,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":17,"AttributeFieldName":"STR9","OperatorId":"18","OperatorValue":"Tomorrow","Value":"","FormatType":"disable"}],"Value":"Tomorrow: date"},{"Priority":9,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":18,"AttributeFieldName":"STR5","OperatorId":"20","OperatorValue":"Yesterday","Value":"","FormatType":"disable"}],"Value":"Yesterday -u003e date"},{"Priority":10,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":19,"AttributeFieldName":"FIELD1","OperatorId":"7","OperatorValue":"u003e","Value":"8","FormatType":"number"}],"Value":"Number u003e5 $ test"},{"Priority":11,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":20,"AttributeFieldName":"STR0","OperatorId":"5","OperatorValue":"Equals","Value":"cat","FormatType":"text"}],"Value":"String u0026 Equals"},{"Priority":12,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":21,"AttributeFieldName":"FIELD2","OperatorId":"5","OperatorValue":"=","Value":"12","FormatType":"number"}],"Value":"number = 12"}],"ElseValue":"testik","Format":4,"DisplayName":"Cripto Test","Description":"desc: Cripto Test","FieldName":" ","PublishStatus":"NotPublished","Name":"CriptoTest","Type":"conditional","AttributeBaseType":"string","IsPersonalization":false}'
DECLARE @parameter1 VARCHAR(8000)='{"ExpressionsArray":[{"Priority":1,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1 and @2 and @3 and @4 and @5 and @6 and @7 and @8 and @9 and @10","Conditions":[{"Position":1,"AttributeFieldName":"STR101","OperatorId":"14","OperatorValue":"Contains","Value":"ci","FormatType":"text"},{"Position":2,"AttributeFieldName":"STR13","OperatorId":"11","OperatorValue":"Between","Value":"2022-08-08,2022-08-12","FormatType":"between dates"},{"Position":3,"AttributeFieldName":"FIELD353","OperatorId":"11","OperatorValue":"Between","Value":"15,19","FormatType":"between numbers"},{"Position":4,"AttributeFieldName":"STR0","OperatorId":"14","OperatorValue":"Contains","Value":"cate","FormatType":"text"},{"Position":5,"AttributeFieldName":"FIELD362","OperatorId":"6","OperatorValue":"u003cu003e","Value":"5","FormatType":"number"},{"Position":6,"AttributeFieldName":"STR28","OperatorId":"13","OperatorValue":"Ends with","Value":"a","FormatType":"text"},{"Position":7,"AttributeFieldName":"STR15","OperatorId":"21","OperatorValue":"One of","Value":"tt","FormatType":"text"},{"Position":8,"AttributeFieldName":"FIELD522","OperatorId":"10","OperatorValue":"u003c=","Value":"7","FormatType":"number"},{"Position":9,"AttributeFieldName":"FIELD649","OperatorId":"6","OperatorValue":"u003cu003e","Value":"5","FormatType":"number"},{"Position":10,"AttributeFieldName":"STR3","OperatorId":"14","OperatorValue":"Contains","Value":"bobo","FormatType":"text"}],"Value":"city good"},{"Priority":2,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":11,"AttributeFieldName":"STR101","OperatorId":"14","OperatorValue":"Contains","Value":"ci","FormatType":"text"}],"Value":"city good2"},{"Priority":3,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":12,"AttributeFieldName":"FIELD339","OperatorId":"11","OperatorValue":"Between","Value":"70,80","FormatType":"between numbers"}],"Value":"very good"},{"Priority":4,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":13,"AttributeFieldName":"STR1","OperatorId":"11","OperatorValue":"Between","Value":"2022-08-02,2022-08-05","FormatType":"between dates"}],"Value":"date between 1"},{"Priority":5,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":14,"AttributeFieldName":"STR11","OperatorId":"5","OperatorValue":"Equals","Value":"lan","FormatType":"text"}],"Value":"lan"},{"Priority":6,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":15,"AttributeFieldName":"STR6","OperatorId":"26","OperatorValue":"This week","Value":"","FormatType":"disable"}],"Value":"This week date"},{"Priority":7,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":16,"AttributeFieldName":"STR7","OperatorId":"19","OperatorValue":"Today","Value":"","FormatType":"disable"}],"Value":"Today - date"},{"Priority":8,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":17,"AttributeFieldName":"STR9","OperatorId":"18","OperatorValue":"Tomorrow","Value":"","FormatType":"disable"}],"Value":"Tomorrow: date"},{"Priority":9,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":18,"AttributeFieldName":"STR5","OperatorId":"20","OperatorValue":"Yesterday","Value":"","FormatType":"disable"}],"Value":"Yesterday -u003e date"},{"Priority":10,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":19,"AttributeFieldName":"FIELD1","OperatorId":"7","OperatorValue":"u003e","Value":"8","FormatType":"number"}],"Value":"Number u003e5 $ test"},{"Priority":11,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":20,"AttributeFieldName":"STR0","OperatorId":"5","OperatorValue":"Equals","Value":"cat","FormatType":"text"}],"Value":"String u0026 Equals"},{"Priority":12,"ShowComplexExpression":false,"ComplexExpression":"@1","Conditions":[{"Position":21,"AttributeFieldName":"FIELD2","OperatorId":"5","OperatorValue":"=","Value":"12","FormatType":"number"}],"Value":"number = 12"}],"ElseValue":"testik","Format":4,"DisplayName":"Cripto Test","Description":"desc: Cripto Test","FieldName":" ","PublishStatus":"NotPublished","Name":"CriptoTest","Type":"conditional","AttributeBaseType":"string","IsPersonalization":false}'
SELECT ISJSON(@parameter) -- @parameter length 2848 - return 1 - OK
SELECT ISJSON(@parameter1)  -- @parameter length 4294 return 0 - NOT OK
SELECT ISJSON(CAST(@parameter1 AS VARCHAR(max)) ) -- return 1 - OK
```

Comment: The problem isn't `ISJSON` it's your data type. The data is being implicitly converted to an `nvarchar` but as you defined the `varchar` as a non-`MAX` length then truncation occurs when it's converted to an `nvarchar(4000)`.

Comment: I would, however, suggest that the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is incomplete as it doesn't state what the data type is of the text value... Probably needs an issue raised against it (might do this later if no one else does or hasn't already).

Comment: used to be an issue in 2016

Comment: Agreed, @lptr . I can't replicate the issue locally, but db<>fiddle does on [2016](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c9029b964e195b3cd2835ca566603a44) (and doesn't on [2019](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c9029b964e195b3cd2835ca566603a44))

Comment: 2019 execplan : `<ScalarOperator ScalarString="isjson(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(max),[@parameter1],0))"><Intrinsic FunctionName="isjson"><ScalarOperator><Convert DataType="nvarchar(max)" Length="2147483647" Style="0" Implicit="1">`…. 2016 execplan: `<ScalarOperator ScalarString="isjson(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(nvarchar(4000),[@parameter1],0))"><Intrinsic FunctionName="isjson"><ScalarOperator><Convert DataType="nvarchar" Length="8000" Style="0" Implicit="1">`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is specifically to do with your choice of data type, `varchar(8000)`. Though not documented, it is very likely that `ISJSON` (at least in SQL Server 2016) expects an `nvarchar`, however, you have defined a `varchar`. As a result, when the value is passed to `ISJSON` it is implicitly cast to an `nvarchar`.

As, however, this value isn't a `MAX` value, and SQL Server doesn't *normally* implicitly convert a non-`MAX` value to a `MAX` one, this means that the value is implicitly converted to an `nvarchar(4000)`, and so for your value which is over 4,000 characters in length, truncation occurs.

As the value is truncated, this then causes the value being checked to no longer be valid, and so `ISJSON` returns `0`, instead of `1`.

The solution, therefore, would be to define your parameters as an `nvarchar(MAX)`; which is the correct data type for JSON in SQL Server.

*This, as [lptr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12403612/lptr) highlights, appears to only be a problem in SQL Server 2016 ([2016](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c9029b964e195b3cd2835ca566603a44) vs [2017](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c9029b964e195b3cd2835ca566603a44) & [2019](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c9029b964e195b3cd2835ca566603a44)). what Microsoft's fix was under the hood is unclear; I can't find any documentation or bug fixes addressing the matter. I would **assume** that the data type isn't implicitly cast to an `nvarchar` and a `varchar` is used, but it *might* implicitly cast it to an `nvarchar(MAX)`.*

Comment: Looking at the query plans https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ee46249550a9d55e25425aab09229260 and https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ee46249550a9d55e25425aab09229260 it appears the fix was simply to always implicitly cast to `nvarchar(max)`, I'm assuming this was special-cased in the compiler, because normally implicit casts never go to `max`